# How to embed Node.js interpreter into C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, node.js

I want to use Node.js scripts in my C/C++ applications. Some people suggested me to start with v8, libev and libeio; but it means rewriting Node.js from scratch.

So, is it possible to embed Node.js into C or C++?

Comment: node.js is actually V8 embedded in a web server. Since your application probably isn't a web server, you can just embed V8 (or any other javascript engine) into it.

Comment: Technically node.js doesn't just do webservers. It can fulfill tons of different roles, but it's really good for HTTP servers (fileservers, webservers, etc). In either case, you're right about just using V8 instead.

Comment: @MAK node.js is not a web server. It integrates a web server module, but it certainly is not a web server. In C++ apps node.js brings loads of modules not available with just v8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is, V8 is written in C++, node.js can run on V8, but unless you have an *extremely* good reason why you would run javascript through C++ you are probably much better served finding an appropriate C++ library and implementing the needed functionality directly in C++. The task of integrating scripting languages and native code is usually not trivial. E.g. [V8 documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html). Qt offers a pretty decent integration between c++ and javascript and it still not trivial to move objects back and forth between script and code.

Comment: There is some effort to port QtScript library to take the advantage of V8 - http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/V8_Port

Answer (score 13):

You should first consider whether it would be *sufficient to implement your application as a C++ module for Node* and then *glue the main part as a Node script*.

Otherwise you may wish to *"re-implement Node"*, by taking the core code as the example and
removing the parts which you don't need (e.g. HTTP module) and then putting your components
into it. The least painful way would be to do a sub-tree merge and ripping-out the build system, then adding prefixes in the build scripts to point to the directory where it lives.
Then you can stop certain parts from being built. However Node's build system contains several parts and it may be quite a difficult job to do.

You can also try re-packaging Node with your stuff loaded by default and changing the name of the executable. However, that is just a more complex way of taking the first approach I have described, you can just install a script in `/usr/bin/` which will go as:

```
  #!/usr/bin/node
  var myAppMain = require('libmyApp');
  myAppMain.withConfig(filename,
  function(err, cnf) {
     if (err) throw err; // parser or file access error
     cnf.evalMe();
  });
```

You can use a JSlint as your parser, then grep for dangerous calls and then `eval(conf_script)` or just use `require(config.js)`, though you will need to add `exports.someMethod = function (...) {...}`. But `require()` is much safer in general, however you may wish to implement a pre-processor for your config which will substitute `exports.someMethod = function (...) {...}` instead of your functions and will append `require('OnlyCallMySafeMethods')` and reject any
attempts to `require('fs')` or other lib which you may be afraid of letting the someone to use.
This sort of safety is just an optional thing you *may wish to have*, it's all up to you really.
Though I suppose you might want to do the bit with `exports.someMethod = ....` substitution and have one `require('myAppConfigLib)` added on the top so the user will just use you API plus anything they may wish to put into their script/config!

***UPDATE:*** There is a quite useful comment on [line 66](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L66) of `src/node.js`:

```
  // To allow people to extend Node in different ways, this hook allows
  // one to drop a file lib/_third_party_main.js into the build
  // directory which will be executed instead of Node's normal loading.
```

Please also note that the contents of `src/` are being compiled to bytecode at build time.

Answer (score 13):

Embedding Node.JS is now officially supported by a Node.JS fork JXcore. Embedding docs are available from [this link](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/blob/master/doc/native/Embedding_Basics.md).

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, and should be the accepted answer imo, exactly the OP was after.

Comment: Appears to be end of life as of 2016

Answer (score 3):

I've build something close to what I think you're looking for:

https://github.com/ZECTBynmo/tacnode

It's a library that allows node.js to be linked statically into a C++ application. It's definitely not polished, but I've used it to launch simple node scripts.

Comment: Tried it but a syntax error in the build script "vcbuild.bat" is worse enough to not spend more time on it.

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation has a page explaining how [how to embed Node.js into C++](https://nodejs.org/api/embedding.html). This has been around since [Node 12.x](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/embedding.html).

There is a [full example in the Node repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b4a962d0e6728157983c709398321fd03e902db0/test/embedding/embedtest.cc). Reproduced below for convenience:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#undef NDEBUG
#endif
#include "node.h"
#include "uv.h"
#include <assert.h>

// Note: This file is being referred to from doc/api/embedding.md, and excerpts
// from it are included in the documentation. Try to keep these in sync.
// Snapshot support is not part of the embedder API docs yet due to its
// experimental nature, although it is of course documented in node.h.

using node::CommonEnvironmentSetup;
using node::Environment;
using node::MultiIsolatePlatform;
using v8::Context;
using v8::HandleScope;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Locker;
using v8::MaybeLocal;
using v8::V8;
using v8::Value;

static int RunNodeInstance(MultiIsolatePlatform* platform,
                           const std::vector<std::string>& args,
                           const std::vector<std::string>& exec_args);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  argv = uv_setup_args(argc, argv);
  std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);
  std::unique_ptr<node::InitializationResult> result =
      node::InitializeOncePerProcess(
          args,
          {node::ProcessInitializationFlags::kNoInitializeV8,
           node::ProcessInitializationFlags::kNoInitializeNodeV8Platform});

  for (const std::string& error : result->errors())
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", args[0].c_str(), error.c_str());
  if (result->early_return() != 0) {
    return result->exit_code();
  }

  std::unique_ptr<MultiIsolatePlatform> platform =
      MultiIsolatePlatform::Create(4);
  V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  V8::Initialize();

  int ret =
      RunNodeInstance(platform.get(), result->args(), result->exec_args());

  V8::Dispose();
  V8::DisposePlatform();

  node::TearDownOncePerProcess();
  return ret;
}

int RunNodeInstance(MultiIsolatePlatform* platform,
                    const std::vector<std::string>& args,
                    const std::vector<std::string>& exec_args) {
  int exit_code = 0;

  node::EmbedderSnapshotData::Pointer snapshot;
  auto snapshot_build_mode_it =
      std::find(args.begin(), args.end(), "--embedder-snapshot-create");
  auto snapshot_arg_it =
      std::find(args.begin(), args.end(), "--embedder-snapshot-blob");
  auto snapshot_as_file_it =
      std::find(args.begin(), args.end(), "--embedder-snapshot-as-file");
  if (snapshot_arg_it < args.end() - 1 &&
      snapshot_build_mode_it == args.end()) {
    const char* filename = (snapshot_arg_it + 1)->c_str();
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    assert(fp != nullptr);
    if (snapshot_as_file_it != args.end()) {
      snapshot = node::EmbedderSnapshotData::FromFile(fp);
    } else {
      uv_fs_t req;
      int statret = uv_fs_stat(nullptr, &req, filename, nullptr);
      assert(statret == 0);
      size_t filesize = req.statbuf.st_size;
      uv_fs_req_cleanup(&req);

      std::vector<char> vec(filesize);
      size_t read = fread(vec.data(), filesize, 1, fp);
      assert(read == 1);
      snapshot = node::EmbedderSnapshotData::FromBlob(vec);
    }
    assert(snapshot);
    int ret = fclose(fp);
    assert(ret == 0);
  }

  std::vector<std::string> errors;
  std::unique_ptr<CommonEnvironmentSetup> setup =
      snapshot ? CommonEnvironmentSetup::CreateFromSnapshot(
                     platform, &errors, snapshot.get(), args, exec_args)
      : snapshot_build_mode_it != args.end()
          ? CommonEnvironmentSetup::CreateForSnapshotting(
                platform, &errors, args, exec_args)
          : CommonEnvironmentSetup::Create(platform, &errors, args, exec_args);
  if (!setup) {
    for (const std::string& err : errors)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", args[0].c_str(), err.c_str());
    return 1;
  }

  Isolate* isolate = setup->isolate();
  Environment* env = setup->env();

  {
    Locker locker(isolate);
    Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
    HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
    Context::Scope context_scope(setup->context());

    MaybeLocal<Value> loadenv_ret;
    if (snapshot) {
      loadenv_ret = node::LoadEnvironment(env, node::StartExecutionCallback{});
    } else {
      loadenv_ret = node::LoadEnvironment(
          env,
          // Snapshots do not support userland require()s (yet)
          "if (!require('v8').startupSnapshot.isBuildingSnapshot()) {"
          "  const publicRequire ="
          "    require('module').createRequire(process.cwd() + '/');"
          "  globalThis.require = publicRequire;"
          "} else globalThis.require = require;"
          "globalThis.embedVars = { nön_ascıı: '️‍' };"
          "require('vm').runInThisContext(process.argv[1]);");
    }

    if (loadenv_ret.IsEmpty())  // There has been a JS exception.
      return 1;

    exit_code = node::SpinEventLoop(env).FromMaybe(1);
  }

  if (snapshot_arg_it < args.end() - 1 &&
      snapshot_build_mode_it != args.end()) {
    snapshot = setup->CreateSnapshot();
    assert(snapshot);

    FILE* fp = fopen((snapshot_arg_it + 1)->c_str(), "w");
    assert(fp != nullptr);
    if (snapshot_as_file_it != args.end()) {
      snapshot->ToFile(fp);
    } else {
      const std::vector<char> vec = snapshot->ToBlob();
      size_t written = fwrite(vec.data(), vec.size(), 1, fp);
      assert(written == 1);
    }
    int ret = fclose(fp);
    assert(ret == 0);
  }

  node::Stop(env);

  return exit_code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just checking out [js-git](https://github.com/creationix/js-git/tree/legacy) which is made for Node.js and also depends on a few other Node.js modules.

However, the same developer wrote a tool [tim-task](https://github.com/creationix/tim-task) to wrap up some common Node.js functions, most importantly `require`, and to pack together some Node.js modules in such a way that it should not depend on Node.js anymore. He used it to make [git-web-platform](https://github.com/creationix/git-web-platform), i.e. js-git packed as a JS file which can be used in browsers. The resulted packed file looks like [this](https://github.com/creationix/git-web-platform/blob/master/build/jsgit.js). This can probably also be used with minor modifications just in pure V8.

This might be useful for you. Note however that this approach will be limited.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good reasons to embed node, including the ability to leverage npm.

Unfortunately JXCore is dying. 
this artice gives some alternatives. 
http://www.goland.org/nodeapps/