# Embedding node.js into a process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to embed node.js into an existing process so I can call Javascript functions from a already running process.  Is this possible and does anyone have examples of doing this?

Comment: After changing terms I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525162/how-to-embed-node-js-interpreter-into-c-c

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for exactly.

- If you want to load the Node runtime into a non-Node application (i.e. written in a different language), try posting the question under that language instead of under node.js and javascript.
- If you are looking to run multiple Node processes in a master/slave relationship, check out the [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) functionality in Node.
- If you want to spawn a new process from your main app, take a look at [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).
- If you want to inject new code into an existing application that is already running, I don't think that is possible unless the existing application is specifically built for it, and even then I don't know if it would be possible with Node. I figure it would be a pretty big security risk if applications could manipulate other applications like that.
- If you want to have communication between separate processes, you can take a look at an IPC module (inter process communications) like [node-ipc](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc).

If my answer didn't help you, feel free to comment and/or adjust your original question to include some more detailed information about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I have an existing runtime that I want to be able to execute Javascript in, in other words embed Javascript in this existing runtime.  I realize I could probably directly use Chrome V8, but then I'd lose much of what node.js provides.  Ideally what I want to do is start a thread, load node.js from that thread and call into node from a native language such as C.

Comment: @user2047298 I think you may be looking for [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).

Comment: Perhaps, although I don't want arbitrary "commands" being executed.  What I want is to load (embed) node.js into my process, give it a bunch of Javascript to have available, and then when something arrives in my process, invoke one of the Javascript methods previously loaded.  It might also be nice to allow other node.js capabilities like listening on a socket to execute requests.

Comment: @toddinpal you could look at [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) which is used to create a controlled command interface. You can have it read from stdin which I'm pretty sure a parent process can write to.